# Oracle: query the tables, but no results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE teacher (
    tid varchar2(40),
    tname varchar2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE student (
    sid varchar2(40),
    sname varchar2(20),
    tid varchar2(40)
);
```

There is a lot of data in these tables, but when I execute the SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM student s, teacher t
WHERE s.tid = t.tid
```

there is nothing. I'm confused about it, why?

Is there anything to do with the "`tid varchar2(40)`"?

Comment: Are you sure that any students have teachers that are also teachers? what does `select tid from student intersect select tid from teacher` return?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: but you should start using explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of the implicit joins in the where clause - especially if you are new to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have same tid in both tables. If you see both having same id and still no result, then you have trailing space or any specail characters at the end(Since ID is referred as Varchar here). Try trim in your query.

```
SELECT *
FROM student s, teacher t
WHERE trim(s.tid) = trim(t.tid);
```

Comment: yeah,that's it,thanks for your advice!one more thing , Hibernate doesn't have the function to trim it ? (cause I use Hibernate to query Teacher in order to get the set of Student who has the same tid)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your `tid` or `sid` fields have invisible trailing spaces. Try to sanitize these fields by trimming whitespace:

```
UPDATE teacher SET tid = TRIM(tid);
UPDATE student SET tid = TRIM(tid), sid = TRIM(sid);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unusual for a column like that to be defined as varchar2. Usually key columns would be integers, and you would not get into this situation.

You should probably look at rebuilding the schema using a more appropriate data type.

Comment: yeah,your are right .i use Hibernate framwork to and define the way to add primary key is <generator class="uuid"/>,so i can deal with the concurent visits. Do u have some advice for me ?

Comment: There's a good discussion of the use of UUID's in Oracle here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2570145300346198113